# How to update Firefox to the latest version ever if you are not using it?

Tags: firefox, updates

I use Firefox from time to time, every time I open it it gets updated with the autoupdate.

The issue I am facing is that it only updates after I open it and if I don't do it for a while it gets with an old version that could be unsecure and my IT department complains as their scanners flag it.

Is there a way to update it ever tho it is not opened? Like checking the version every startup or alike?

Comment: Potential powershell script at https://github.com/auberginehill/update-mozilla-firefox

Comment: Could be a solution, I was expecting the tipical agent tho.

Comment: I did find https://wiki.mozilla.org/Windows_Service_Silent_Update which appears to be the native service to perform the updates, but it wasnt clear how you would go about using it outside of Firefox itself. It seemed like you would still have to download and extract the latest version yourself which means doing all the work to see if an update was needed to begin with. It might just be simpler to have Firefox start up with your computer a couple of times a week purely for update purposes.

Comment: Many Linux distros do that alongside other system updates. Anywhere else there's no "native" way to do it.

Comment: Are you allowed to download and install software? If so, just get the latest installation files from Mozilla. Use another browser to download. Alternative: set a reminder in a calendar app to start Firefox periodically.